# How to enable Gmap module in Drupal 7

Tags: google-maps

I just enabled the Gmap module in Drupal 7. You can see it in the picture below.
[image: picture]

In Drupal 6, after the gmap is enabled, you can do the setting for any content type in **/admin/content/node-type/story** under **location information**.

But I don't see how to do it in Drupal 7.

[image: locationTab]

I can't neither found it as a field type to add to content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmap for drupal 7 is missing a js file. See http://drupal.org/node/1061444. The discussion may lead you to solution.

Comment: I tried to apply the patch but I get this message: (it seems like if the **gmap module** it is not enabled, but it is...                MESSAGE: `(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: gmap.module
|===================================================================
|--- gmap.module
|+++ gmap.module
--------------------------
File to patch: 
`

Comment: **It seems like if the gmap module it is not enabled, but it is enabled**

Comment: I upload a capture above to show that the location tab is missing in 'article' content type.

Comment: Fixed> I just enabled the Location node module.